# How to find area of intersection of disk and cone?

Tags: regions, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the area of intersection of a cone and a disk which is a circular slice of the cone rotated through a particular angle about the apex of the cone. I've defined the cone using a set of inequalities with ImplicitRegion and have found a parametrization for the circle. I'm confident I have found the right equations because plotting RegionUnion produces what I expect to see, for example for the disk rotated through 1 degree:

```
R = 1.4;
d = 30;
T = Pi/180;
cone = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= (z Tan[R/d])^2,0 <= z < 1.2*d}, {x, y, z}];
disk = ParametricRegion[{d Sin[T] - r Cos[T] Cos[t], r Sin[t],d Cos[T] - r Cos[t] Sin[T]}, {{r, 0, 1.42}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}}];
Region[cone]
Region[disk]
Region[RegionUnion[cone, disk]]
```

[image: cone]

[image: disk]

[image: union of cone and disk]

However, I can't get it to plot the intersection or calculate the area of the intersection:

```
Region[RegionIntersection[cone, disk]]
```

produces the output

[image: RegionIntersection output]

and asking it for the area of intersection,

```
Area[RegionIntersection[cone, disk]]
```

gives the output:
[image: Area output]

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working and how to calculate the area of intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
In[7]:= RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[cone, disk]]

Out[7]= 4.78199
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it, obtaing Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException]. SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] in MMA 11.3.

Comment: I tried this in version 11.2. I'll try 11.3 tomorrow and file a bug report if I get the same error.

Comment: Don't trouble. I already submitted that.